# Can jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut be tweeked to use CSS transitions?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery for animations. Part of those use the .fadeIn and .fadeOut API. This works fine just about everywhere except on iOS devices. on iOS devices the fades look choppy and are generally not smooth at all, even over a 1 or 2 seconds fade.

Is there any way to rewrite or create a similar function that would use CSS transitions as they seem to be much smoother on on iOS than the method jQuery uses.

Comment: are you useing jQuery mobile?

Comment: @Neal - No. they site is not iOS or mobile specific, just trying to make it work there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best fadeIn/fadeOut using CSS3 transitions I've coded. It supports all of their signatures. So far, no bugs found. Feel free to reuse

```
var hasCSSTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

hasCSSTransitions && (function ($) {
    $.fn.fadeIn = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.filter(function (i, elem) {
                        return $.css(elem, 'display') === 'none' || !$.contains(elem.ownerDocument, elem);
                    })
                    .css('opacity', 0)
                    .show()
                    .end()
                .transition({
                    opacity: 1
                }, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    $.fn.fadeOut = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        var newCallback = function () {
            $(this).hide();
        };

        // Account for `.fadeOut(callback)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'function') {
            callback = speed;
            speed = undefined;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(options)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'object' && typeof speed.complete === 'function') {
            callback = speed.complete;
            delete speed.complete;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(duration, callback)`.
        if (typeof easing === 'function') {
          callback = easing;
          easing = undefined;
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            newCallback = function () {
                $(this).hide();
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }

        return this.transition({
            opacity: 0
        }, speed, easing, newCallback);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This requires [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin from Rico. It's just a wrapper with a similar signature than animate() but for using css3.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'transition'` Does this also require an additional resource?

Comment: @Isius YEAH!! Sorry about that. Thank you for pointing it out, I've just added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .fadeIn() and .fadeOut(), use .animate() and you can perform all the custom css animations you like!

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: My understanding is that animate and the fade* methods not actually use css transitions. I *think* the setup a timer and effect the changes a increiment at a time until the full change is complete. the issue is that this isnt accelerated on iOS and things become choppy as frames get misses. CSS transitions are HW accelerated and run much much smoother.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of iOS? In the 4.3 update Mobile Safari got a brand new JavaScript engine, that likely would improve your JS performance. The only other recommendation I can make would be to use a mobile optimized framework, like jquery mobile or jqtouch.