# How to add promise to an overloaded jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, promise, overloading

I'm using the code from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819834/1024808) to overwrite jQuery's fadeOut to use css transitions.

**Code**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fadeIn = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.filter(function (i, elem) {
                        return $.css(elem, 'display') === 'none' || !$.contains(elem.ownerDocument, elem);
                    })
                    .css('opacity', 0)
                    .show()
                    .end()
                .transition({
                    opacity: 1
                }, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    $.fn.fadeOut = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        var newCallback = function () {
            $(this).hide();
        };

        // Account for `.fadeOut(callback)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'function') {
            callback = speed;
            speed = undefined;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(options)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'object' && typeof speed.complete === 'function') {
            callback = speed.complete;
            delete speed.complete;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(duration, callback)`.
        if (typeof easing === 'function') {
          callback = easing;
          easing = undefined;
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            newCallback = function () {
                $(this).hide();
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }

        return this.transition({
            opacity: 0
        }, speed, easing, newCallback);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This works well for

**"Normal call"**

```
$('body')
    .find('.item')
        .fadeOut()
    .end()
    // ...
```

but not with

**"Promise call"**

```
$('body')
    .find('.item')
        .fadeOut(function(){ $(this).remove() })
        .promise()
        .done(function allDone(){ /*...*/ })
    .end()
    // ...
```

which I want to use so that allDone() runs only once after all the items are faded out. So I modified the code (based on what I could figure out from googling) to

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fadeOut = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();    //################# Added

        var newCallback = function () {
            $(this).hide();

            dfd.resolve(this);    //################# Added
        };

        // Account for `.fadeOut(callback)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'function') {
            callback = speed;
            speed = undefined;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(options)`.
        if (typeof speed === 'object' && typeof speed.complete === 'function') {
            callback = speed.complete;
            delete speed.complete;
        }

        // Account for `.fadeOut(duration, callback)`.
        if (typeof easing === 'function') {
          callback = easing;
          easing = undefined;
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            newCallback = function () {
                $(this).hide();
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
                dfd.resolve(this);    //################# Added
            };
        }

        this.transition({    //################# return was moved below
            opacity: 0
        }, speed, easing, newCallback);

        return dfd.promise();
    };
}(jQuery));
```

which seemed to make the "promise call" work but now I get `undefined is not a function` in the console on the "normal call". Am I going about this the wrong way?

How can I satisfy both calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why your custom `.fadeOut` function would not work with the [`.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), assuming that the `.transition` method it uses properly sets up the animation queue. If `.promise` doesn't work, file a bug against that "transit" plugin you're using, don't try to come up with something on your own.

The reason that you get an `undefined is not a function` exception is that `.promise()` does return a Promise object, which has all kinds of [chainable methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) but is not a jQuery collection, and does not have an `.end()` method! You are breaking the chain, you will need to use

```
var body = $('body');
body.find('.item')
    .fadeOut(function(){ $(this).remove() })
    .promise()
    .done(function allDone(){ /*...*/ });
body.… // the rest
```